# UST bootstrapping (coupon bearing or strips)

Tags: fixed-income, bond

how common is it to use the US STRIP market directly to bootstrap a par yield curve? I am having quite a few problems using cubic (peicewise) splines on coupon bearing yield curve, but I see a fair few prices on bbg for STRIPs so wanted to know if this is an equivalent/acceptable method.

i do understand obviously it is not as liquid as coupon bearing market and that itself can have some implications, but what is the magnitude of difference in liquidity? are we talking 100m vs 1tn or 50bn vs 75bn type numbers?

Comment: What are the "a few problems" specifically? Generally speaking STRIPS aren't used for building coupon curves.

Comment: @Helin thanks for coming back. Let me describe in a bit of detail:

Comment: @Helin 
I have a list of every treasury issue that is in existence (coupon bearing). to keep things simple i am using issues post 2022 to calibrate my yield curve. 

I am using excel solver to fit the curve with different peicewise cubic polynomials (similar to tuckmans method described) at knot points. I have adjusted for specials to keep them in the curve (the adjustment is small anyway). 

The fit is bad (in excess of 10bps of errors between model / market for instruments in the calibration). Further, bonds not in the calibration set have errors > 100bps.

Comment: just to be clear - i have also tried this with even more recent issues, i.e. just OTRs (this remediates the problem of the calibrated instruments pricing errors) - but older bonds have some errors in excess of 100bps still (therefore, I thought I should include more bonds in the calibration).

Comment: That sounds like an implementation issue, not an input issue. This shouldn't happen. I recommend that you check your methodology/code.

Comment: typically would you suggest just having OTRs/CTDs in the calibration set (+ may be some bills at the short end)?

Comment: Nowadays it doesn't matter much, but typically you don't include OTRs. CTDs that are extremely dislocated due to short squeeze should also be excluded. Bills are typically not used either.

Comment: you dont want to add OTR just due to their (potential) liquidity premium?

Comment: That and financing advantage, but as said, not that big of a deal nowadays.

Comment: you were right - operator error here. thanks for the help in any case.